# Sum arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these arrays:

```
// I want to calculate these arrays each other.
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [1,2,3]
var c = [3,4,5]
// ->
var result = [5, 8, 11]
```

I can calculate two array with below method but how can I sum **n** arrays?

```
Array.prototype.Sum = function (arr) {
    var s = [];
    if (arr != null && this.length == arr.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var c = this[i] + arr[i]
            s.push(c);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `a.sum(b).sum(c)`? Note lower case *s*, `Sum` is not a constructor. ;-)

Comment: You want something like `zipWith`.

Comment: @RobG I have about 5k arrays like that.

Comment: @Lazy—if you have that many, you should find the looping answers much faster than those using built–in methods, see [*http://jsperf.com/summing-arrays-again*](http://jsperf.com/summing-arrays-again) where loops are 10 times faster than built–ins. Don't judge a solution by the lines of code. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming

```
var arrays = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [3,4,5]
];
```

Using your `Sum` with EcmaScript 5 array methods,

```
var result = arrays.reduce(function(arr1, arr2){
    return arr1.Sum(arr2);
});
```

Alternatively, consider not polluting `Array.prototype` and just using something like (ES5)

```
var result = arrays.reduce(function(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.map(function(num, index){
        return num+arr2[index];
    });
});
```

Or, simplifying using EcmaScript 6 arrow functions,

```
var result = arrays.reduce(
    (arr1, arr2) => arr1.map(
        (num, index) => num+arr2[index]
    )
);
```

Comment: This is not it, `result` gives `[6,6,12]` when it should be `[5,8,11]`

Comment: @elclanrs True, fixed.

Comment: Be aware that the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) functions are parts of the ECMAScript 5 specification, which is only supported by [modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/). If that's an issue for you, you will have to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim), which adds the functionality to older browsers.

Comment: Note that for loops are nearly always faster than methods like *map* and *reduce*. Slightly more code, but faster.

Comment: Oh, and if the built–ins have been pollyfilled, they will be very, very much slower than plain loops.

Answer (score 3):

With this function, you can sum several arrays and you don't need to "encapsulate" your arrays into another array...

Also, it works on old browsers.

```
function Sum(){
  if (arguments.length == 0){
    return null;
  }
  var s = arguments[0];
  for(var j = 1; j < arguments.length; j++) {
     var arr = arguments[j];
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         s[i] = s[i] + arr[i];
     }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Just call `Sum(a, b)`  or `Sum(a, b, c)` ...

You can put it in your prototype too if you want (and make little changes to use `this` if you want to sum in place).

Comment: The first *if* block is redundant. If no arguments are provided, *s* will be undefined, the outer *for* loop will not run so *undefined* will be returned. Or you could do `return s || null;`, but *undefined* makes more sense to me. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A plain old ECMAScript 3 solution:

```
var arrays = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5]
];

function sum() {
  var sum = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    for(var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; ++j)
      sum[j] = (sum[j] || 0) + arguments[i][j];
  } return sum;
}

sum.apply(this, arrays);              // [ 5, 8, 11 ]
sum(arrays[0], arrays[1], arrays[2]); // [ 5, 8, 11 ]
```

Comment: Loops are fast, you might find `sum.push(...)` faster than `sum[j] = ...`.

Comment: That wouldn't preserve the semantics, though. I'm accessing each `sum[j]` `arguments.length` times (given the input arrays have the same length).

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sum(b).sum(c);
```

That should do it.